# Using "from" as a script argument in Python

Tags: python

My assignment requires that "from" be used as an argument for the command line input.

```
p = optparse.OptionParser()
p.add_option("--from")
p.add_option("--to")
p.add_option("--file", default="carla_coder.ics")
options, arguments = p.parse_args()

print options.from
```

obviously, "from" is a Python keyword... is there any way to get around this? Basically, the script should be run using 
`file.py --from=dd/mm/yyyy --to=dd/mm/yyyy --file=file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [the `dest` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.dest) to specify a name:

```
p.add_option("--from", dest="foo")

print options.foo
```

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yes. I just wanted to illustrate that you could choose any name. In theory, "From" would even work, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use Python's `getattr` function:

```
getattr(options, 'from')
```

Will behave like `options.from`, except that the attribute name doesn't have to follow Python's usual variable naming rules (including keyword conflicts).